# sha1 not working with Auth Phone

Tags: android, firebase

in my app I have records with google and facebook, they work normal for me, now add with phone, but using it sends me this error:

**This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console**

but obviously I already put the sha1 and the package because google and facebook go well, just in case I'm running it on a physical device, with real cell phone number, but it does not recognize anything

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what is going on.

May be at some point in your while "**android studio upgrade** the **debug keystore might have changed** which means your builds will now have a new SHA1.

**Fix:**

Just add new SHA1 of your debug keystore to your Firebase console and this should be fixed.

**You can also do it with Android Studio.**

Follow these steps:

1. Select Tools shown at the top bar in studio.
2. then select Firebase
3. Click Authentication
4. Select Connect and then finally click Sync.

This would sync your project settings to the Firebase console.

Hope this helps.